# Why is my function returning `None`?

Tags: python, function

I built a calculation and it works:

```
num = input("How many numbers would you like to add? ") 

list = []
for x in range(num):
    list.append(input('Number: '))

a = 0
for x in list:

    a=a+x
    print a
```

But when I try to make a function on of this, simply doesn't work. Can you please direct me?

```
list = []

def adding():
    num = input("How many numbers would you like to add? ") 

    for x in range(num):

        list.append(input('Number: '))

        a = 0
        for x in list:
            a=a+x

print adding()
```

Comment: 1) you need to use `return` from the function 2) please do not call a list `list` since you override the function of the same name

Comment: If you want your function to return something, it needs to have a return statement.

Comment: "Does not work" is not very helpful. What doesn't work? How doesn't it work?

Comment: What do you mean *"doesn't work"*? You don't `return` anything, why wouldn't it return `None`?

Comment: In Py2 `input()` is generally considered unsafe as it evaluates the input, use `int(raw_input(...))`.

Answer (score 4):

Functions without explicit `return`s or empty `return`s will return `None`.

```
>>> def foo():
...     print("Hello")
...
>>> f = foo()
Hello
>>> f is None
True
```

If you don't want this, use a `return` at the end of your function to return some value.

---

Some other tips.

### Make your function only do one thing:

Currently your function is getting input, creating a list, *and* summing everything. This is a lot. You'll find that if you make your functions smaller, you'll get some nice benefits. You might consider something like this:

```
def prompt_for_number_of_inputs():
    return int(input("How many elements are there in the list? ")

def prompt_for_elements(num_elements):
    return [int(input("Enter a number: ")) for _ in range(num_elements)]

def sum_elements_in_list(li):
    return sum(li)
```

so you might use it like this:

```
num_elements = prompt_for_number_of_inputs()
my_list = prompt_for_elements(num_elements)
print("The sum of all the elements is {0}".format(sum_elements_in_list(my_list))
```

#### Don't shadow Python built-ins:

If you call your variables the same thing as Python builtins, you'll find yourself in trouble. See here:

```
>>> a = list()
>>> a
[]
>>> list = [1,2,3]
>>> a = list()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Normally `list()` would create an empty list (as seen above), but this is impossible because you've bound an object to the name `list`. Look at other builtins which could be shadowed [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning anything.
Your indentation is incorrect.
You shouldn't use python builtins as variable names (`list`).
(Note: `_` is often used as a disposable variable)

```
def adding():
    num = int(raw_input("How many numbers would you like to add? ")) 
    lst = []

    for _ in range(num):
        lst.append(int(raw_input('Number: ')))

    a = 0
    for x in lst:
        a += x
    return a
```

You don't really need the second loop as `return sum(lst)` would do the same thing.
Alternatively, you don't need `lst` at all:

```
def adding():
    num = int(raw_input("How many numbers would you like to add? ")) 

    a = 0
    for _ in range(num):
        x = int(raw_input('Number: '))
        a += x
    return a
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your variable name for the list as it shadows the built-in name and added the return statement. Works as you intended it to.

```
sumlist = []

def adding():
    num = input("How many numbers would you like to add? ") 

    for x in range(int(num)):

        sumlist.append(int(input('Number: ')))

        a = 0
        for x in sumlist:
            a=a+x

    return a

print(adding())
```

Comment: You should put `sumlist` inside the function, otherwise you're playing with a global variable, which is totally preventable here.